# "Dragon Dice", a historical gambling game involved in the development of probability

Tags: mathematics, probability

"Dragon Dice" was a simple gambling game which rolled a few dice, and 1s were special in some way. A European noble played this game with his friends, who would lose a lot of money to him and then refuse to play this game any more.

This game was notable in that people normally calculate the probability of winning incorrectly; they incorrectly estimate the chance of the special case and thus think the game is profitable when it is not.

However, I have not been able to find this game in any search engine, as results are polluted by a different "Dragon Dice" game made by TSR. Does anyone have a reference to the original game I am mentioning?

Comment: Isn't it the [Chevalier de Méré](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/ChevalierDeMere.shtml) in connection with Pascal ?

Answer (score 2):

My recollection was incorrect; the game is called Dragon Die, and comes from https://gamebalanceconcepts.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/level-4-probability-and-randomness/. The dice game used historically to abuse perception of probability was named something else (though Dragon Die also satisfies that criterion).